# Ordered Map / Hash Table in R

Tags: r, hashtable, associative-array

While working with lists i've noticed an issue that i didn't expect.

```
result5 <- vector("list",length(queryResults[[1]]))
for(i in 1:length(queryResults[[1]])){
    id <- queryResults[[1]][i]
    result5[[id]] <-getPrices(id)
}
```

The problem is that after this code runs instead of the result staying the same size (w/e queryResults[[1]] is) it goes up to the last index creating a bunch of null entries in the middle.

result5 current stores a number of int,double lists so it looks like :
result5[[index(int)]][[row]][col]

While on it's own it's not too problematic I would rather avoid that simply for easier size calculations later on.

For clarification, id is an integer. And in the given case for loop offers same performance, but greater convenience than the apply functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing seems like the easiest way of doing it is :

Using a hash package to convert it using a hash using :

```
result6 <- hash(queryResults[[1]],lapply(queryResults[[1]],getPrices))
```

And if it needs to get accessed calling 
result6[[toString(id)]]
With the difference in performance being marginal, albeit it's still fairly annoying having to include toString in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what your question is, but judging by the structure of the loop, you probably want

```
result5[[i]] <- getPrices(id)
```

rather than `result5[[id]] <- getPrices(id)`.

Comment: In that case it would be simpler to just use lapply, the problem is that since id != i, i want to store value as being associated to the id it's based off, instead of a random number.